# Extra Control inserted into Key View Loop in NSScrollView - Text View in Catalina

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

The default behavior for an NSScrollView - Text View in Catalina has changed. If the Text View has enough text to show a scroll bar, there is an extra control inserted into the Key View Loop after the NSScrollView has become firstResponder. Mojave does not show this extra control in the Key View Loop.

The 2nd control is a NSScroller contained in the Scroll View. NSScroller as firstResponder doesn't appear to have any functionality (e.g. arrow keys do not have any effect).

Can this behavior be turned off? Is there a way to make the ScrollView have a single responder in Catalina?

One thing I tried is setting "Refuses First Responder" of the NSScroller to false, but this had no effect.

Note: Full Keyboard Access (the Catalina equivalent) must be turned on to reproduce this.

Comment: `NSScrollView` doesn't have tab stops and a tab stop isn't a `NSScroller`. What do you mean by "tab stop"? Is the extra "tab stop" visible in TextEdit? How do you make the scroll view or a scroller first responder?

Comment: @Willeke I changed the Tab Stop language. Is it a control inserted into the Key View Loop that can be navigated to via the tab key.

Comment: Did you set up the key view loop in IB?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason NSScroller accepts first responder is so that if all the subviews of your scroll view refuse first responder you still have a way to scroll the scroll view. While the NSScroller is first responder, if I hit page up/page down on my keyboard it scrolls the scroll view. If you want to disable this behavior you can:

```
scrollView.verticalScroller.refusesFirstResponder = YES;
scrollView.horizontalScroller.refusesFirstResponder = YES;
```